# Array max length not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

When I `click` on an image it should be adding it to an `array`, however the `max lenght` of the `array` is 6, therefore if there are already **6 object**s in the `array` it should `alert` and stop letting the user `click` on any new image.

When I run the following I can keep adding images and the `alert` never happens.

```
      jQuery('body').on('change', '.masonry .item :checkbox', function () {
        var urls = [];
        urls.length = 6;
        if (jQuery(urls.length > 6)) {
          alert("Puoi aggiungere un massimo di 6 immagini");
        } else {
          jQuery('.masonry .item :checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            urls.push(jQuery(this).next('label').find('img').attr('src'));
          });
        }
      });
```

Comment: Whats this: `jQuery(urls.length > 6)` This will be something like `$(false)` or `$(true)`

Comment: @Rajesh I thought that is how you set the length of an array `var urls = [];`

Comment: No. Just `urls.length`  would do it

Comment: @Rajesh yes and if it true means that the array length is more than 6, or at least this is what I thought

Comment: `if (jQuery(urls.length > 6)) {` should be just `if (urls.length > 6) {`!

Comment: @Rajesh I have tried your suggestion but I can keep adding images

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir ok I will try again, i did tried before tho and It kept adding

Comment: + it has no meaning! The array is empty and you're setting the length directly!

Comment: I assume you want the user to only check 6 checkboxes! Right?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir sorry could you explain and possibly elaborate it more into an answer? I just tried this and it didn't work tho `if (urls.length > 6) {` as I keep adding images regardless of the set length = 6

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes exactly

Comment: urls.length = 6; ? you will never get urls.length > 6. remove --> urls.length = 6;

Comment: @DanielH check yoruself https://jsfiddle.net/ya7uefet/8/

Comment: @DanielH that will make no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to check the length of the checked items, not an empty array.

```
jQuery('body').on('change', '.masonry .item :checkbox', function () {
    var urls = [];
    var checkedItems = jQuery('.masonry .item :checkbox:checked'); // get the checked items
    if (checkedItems.length > 6) {                                 // if the checked items are more than 6, ...
        alert("No! No! No! Only 6!");
        jQuery(this).prop("checked", false);  //<<< UNCHECK THE ELEMENT JUST CHECKED SO THE COUNT REMAINS 6
    } else {
        checkedItems.each(function () {
            urls.push(jQuery(this).next('label').find('img').attr('src'));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: almost but i can still add it after the alert, check https://jsfiddle.net/ya7uefet/10/

Comment: @RobertoMarras You want to undo the checking if there is more than 6 items?

Comment: @RobertoMarras Check the new update (look for the `//<<<`)!

Comment: This works as I cannot add anymore images however do you have any idea why the alert isn't happening?

Comment: _isn't happening?_ Could explain more!

Comment: i get no alert at all. however I cannot click on the 7th element so it does work, it is just the alert that doesn't pop up

Comment: You probably checked the **"don't bother me again checkbox"** on one of the previous alerts!

Comment: oh well I don't understand why it isn't giving the alert but at least i cannot add more than 6, but it doesn't make any sense,  the console gives me no error and it should just alert

Comment: Wait I'll take a screen shot to give you an example of what I meant by the last comment!

Comment: Here is what I'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK877.png! When the alert box pops up a lot, the browser will show you this option and you probably check it by accident!

Answer (score 0):

use  `if (urls.length > 6)` instead of `if (jQuery(urls.length > 6))`

This is working as expected.

```js
var urls = [];
urls.length = 6;
document.write(urls.length);
document.write("<br>");
document.write(urls.length > 6)
```

/*declare urls array outside of your method, use click event and `event.preventDefault();` to stop checkbox to being check. */

```
var urls = [];

jQuery('body').on('click', '.masonry .item :checkbox', function (event) {
          //alert(urls.length);
            if (urls.length > 5) {
              alert("Puoi aggiungere un massimo di 6 immagini");
              event.preventDefault();
            } else {
            //alert(jQuery(this).next('label').find('img').attr('src'))
         urls.push(jQuery(this).next('label').find('img').attr('src'));

            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your urls array as a global variable.
Remove urls.length=6; it has no effect.
Modify your if condition to
If (urls.length >6)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `src`s of at most 6 checked `input`s, you can create an `object` in which you can set and delete items as per their `checked` status. Also, by using `click` event, you can prevent the checkbox from being `checked` unnecessarily (which will require you to uncheck it manually). Find the working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh214/ya7uefet/20/) and the working snippet below.

```js
var urls={};
console.clear();
jQuery('body').on('click', '.masonry .item :checkbox', function (e) {
 var this_id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
  var is_checked = jQuery(this).is(":checked");
   if(is_checked){
      if (Object.keys(urls).length < 6){
         urls[this_id] = jQuery(this).next('label').find('img').attr('src');
      } else {
       alert("Puoi aggiungere un massimo di 6 immagini");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
   } else {
     delete(urls[this_id]);
   }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="masonry"><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_1" value="valuable" id="thing_1"><label for="thing_1"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_2" value="valuable" id="thing_2"><label for="thing_2"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_3" value="valuable" id="thing_3"><label for="thing_3"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_4" value="valuable" id="thing_4"><label for="thing_4"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_5" value="valuable" id="thing_5"><label for="thing_5"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_6" value="valuable" id="thing_6"><label for="thing_6"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_7" value="valuable" id="thing_7"><label for="thing_7"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_8" value="valuable" id="thing_8"><label for="thing_8"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_9" value="valuable" id="thing_9"><label for="thing_9"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_10" value="valuable" id="thing_10"><label for="thing_10"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_11" value="valuable" id="thing_11"><label for="thing_11"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_12" value="valuable" id="thing_12"><label for="thing_12"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_13" value="valuable" id="thing_13"><label for="thing_13"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_14" value="valuable" id="thing_14"><label for="thing_14"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_15" value="valuable" id="thing_15"><label for="thing_15"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_16" value="valuable" id="thing_16"><label for="thing_16"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_17" value="valuable" id="thing_17"><label for="thing_17"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_18" value="valuable" id="thing_18"><label for="thing_18"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_19" value="valuable" id="thing_19"><label for="thing_19"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div><div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="thing_20" value="valuable" id="thing_20"><label for="thing_20"><img class="img-responsive" src=""></label></div></div>
```

Comment: @RobertoMarras check this now

Comment: @RobertoMarras, okay np

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, following code is causing issue:

```js
jQuery('.masonry .item :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
  urls.push(jQuery(this).next('label').find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

Say you have 10 images, so on every click, you are pushing 10 times. You should only push current element once. Try checking if element exists. If yes, do not push it.

Following is a sample fiddle of how I would do it. It does not use jQuery,, but you can adapt your code accordingly.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/7f9yw0rL/1/)

---

**Edit**

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ya7uefet/12/)

Issue is:

```js
jQuery('body').on('change', '.masonry .item :checkbox', function() {
    var urls = [];
```

You are initialising `urls` in every click. So it will always have `length = 0`

It should be outside the handler's scope.

Comment: this looks promising, could you elaborate it in jQuery based on the code in the question for future users?

Comment: hmm  but now it isn't removing the items if I uncheck them

Comment: I guess you will have to code extra for that. And that is not covered in question. Please try yourself and if you are stuck somewhere, please feel free to add a comment

Answer (score 0):

check this solution, hope it helps, you can check the console.log to see the updated url and urls count.

1st declare array urls out side the change event.

inside `if` using the to stop check more img

inside `else` empty urls array first (in case you are uncheck one checkbox, in that case you don't want to push, you want to take it out, to make it simple just empty that list and add each checked to array (for sure you need to improve this but for now this is the fastest working solution))

I have two console log at the end so you can verify the urls and length.

```
var urls = [];
jQuery('body').on('change', '.masonry .item :checkbox', function() {
  if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 6) {
    alert("Puoi aggiungere un massimo di 6 immagini");
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    // Ensures this code runs AFTER the browser handles click however it wants.
    setTimeout(function() {
      $checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
    }, 0);
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
      urls = [];
    jQuery('.masonry .item :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      urls.push(jQuery(this).next('label').find('img').attr('src'));
    });
  }
    console.log('this urls-->' + urls);
    console.log('this urls length-->' + urls.length);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/5rLh3bq2/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can instead get the length of the checked elements at the time the checkboxes are clicked. It's a bit more straightforward. I also prevented any checkbox after 6 from being enabled.

```
var urls = []; // if you wish to use it outside, make it global

$('.masonry :checkbox').on('click', function(e){

  var selected = $('.masonry :checkbox:checked');

  if( selected.length > 6 ){
    alert( 'Sorry, no more than 6' );
    e.preventDefault(); // stops the checkbox from being selected
    return;
  }

  // do what you wish with the selected ones
  // selected.each()

})
```

Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/h3raldo/pen/vmOXrJ